# Can't access "from" data when requesting meta API Comments

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I try to setup my meta application but I face some problems.

Whenever I request : {post-id}?fields=comments{from}, I always get a permission error. execpt if, the only comment is from me.

{
"error": {
"message": "(#200) Permissions error",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 200,
"fbtrace_id": "Aur70AIfKePgxGZQhlQtzBM"
}
}

I use a page access token and I already debugged it. Is there something I'am missing like a permission? I'am only talking about comments inside the posts of the account related to the access token (mine for the example).

I have the following permissions:

pages_show_list
ads_management
business_management
pages_messaging
instagram_basic
instagram_manage_comments
instagram_content_publish
instagram_manage_messages
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_engagement
public_profile